Short Story. Spaceship controls are designed to perfectly match the pschological make up of the pilot. Emergency attempt to fly another's ship
I think I read this in the 80s probably in an anthology from a UK library.
All spaceships are individually designed for their pilot to match the things they like and the way their mind works.
There is an emergency in which a pilot is required to fly a ship designed for another man, to get some stranded people home.
They have some time before he must fly and he practises again and again using the unfamiliar controls and a computer simulator. In every simulation he crashes and everyone dies.
One attempt on the simulator is being watched by another man who says "You did okay that time!" . The pilot does not mention that he 'landed' some distance underground in that simulation.  He tries and tries again but he cannot adapt to the unfamiliar ship controls.
Then he has an idea - adaptation works both ways - he guts the control room of the unfamiliar ship and rebuilds the controls to be as close to his own as he can. He repaints everything in his own cabin's colours. He even changes parts he will not use in the flight and can only be seen in his peripheral vision just so they will look familiar. The (injured?) pilot whose controls he destroys is furious with him.

 It works and he is able to safely fly the people home.


Fast Trip by James White. It's in his Futures Past collection.I knew it was his, but it took me a while to find it. It's actually the ship's doctor who says "adaptation works both ways".

If so would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278790/70s-sci-fi-novel-pilot-tears-apart-cockpit-to-rebuild-it-in-a-pattern-he-is-fam/278796#278796

Yes, that is it. I confirmed it by reading a summary herehttps://www.sectorgeneral.com/shortstories/fasttrip.html

@JudithJones You can read the whole story at the Internet Archive.
